# Testing mobile website on 3g

Tags: testing, mobile, 3g

I've been searching high and low to try and find some software with which I can test my mobile websites performance on a 3g connection. I also want to be able to monitor the calls so I can breakdown which parts are taking the most time.

I want something like the network tab on firebug or safari web inspector. I know Charles can be used by throttling the connection on my computer and then connection my phone via wi-fi, but I really want to test using an actual 3g connection.

Anyone got any advice on the best testing methods or software available?

Answer (score 0):

I am looking into the same thing myself.
So far I have found the following solutions. All of them not completely to my satisfaction though.

**Android emulator using [netspeed](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#netspeed)** 
 + Manipulate netspeed (manual, umts, gprs, etc..) 
 + Manipulate network delays (latency)
 - Not an actual device
 - android only

**Chrome browser desktop + ADB + chrome browser mobile** ([remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging)) 
 - Only in chrome browser
 + actual device
 - android only
 - Only wifi speed (so no umts, gprs, etc..)

**General**
 1. Record http traffic and replay in a load driver.
 2. Use a WAN emulator that will simulate the various Wi-Fi conditions, higher latency, dropped packets etc
 3. [Webwait](http://webwait.com/) to measure page load times (basic)
 4.[Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/)

Hope it is usefull!